# get array value by key in mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays

It seems a bit strange but as I understand the following code in mysql defines an array.

```
SET @arr = 'a,b,c';
```

i know how to access key for special value,

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b',@arr); // output 2
```

in mysql first key is 1

But I don't know how to access the value by key. Can anyone guide me for this?

Comment: ```SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ',', N), ',', -1)```

Comment: thanks, its true only when each item has 1 letter

Comment: *its true only when each item has 1 letter* Who tells you this strange words? test...

Comment: I am sorry. I can't speak English well, maybe I didn't understand what you meant, maybe you didn't understand what I meant either. If we change the array in this way, is your solution still correct?
@arr = 'aa,bb,cc'

Comment: ```SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('aa,bb,cc', ',', 2), ',', -1);``` => ```'bb'```

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary to say that not all words are the same length. any way thanks

Comment: The functon output does not depend on the items lengths. Read this function definition carefully.